# "No data available" in Zeppelin charts

Tags: apache-spark-sql, visualization, apache-zeppelin

I'm having problems creating visualizations with Zeppelin. I've got a dataset with about 600 million records. It's stored in an HDFS cluster and I'm able to load as a Spark dataframe:

```
%spark.pyspark
input_hdfs_path = u'hdfs://cluster-master:9000/data/CDR_*.parquet'
df = spark.read.format('parquet').load(input_hdfs_path)
df.registerTempTable("df")
```

I'm interested in creating histograms on the length of the CDR (field `CDR_LENGTH`):

```
%sql
select ROUND(CDR_LENGTH, -2) as duration, count(*) as count
from df
group by 1
order by 1
```

I do get the appropriate results in the Table tab (with two columns, `duration` and `count`), but when going to the bar chart tab (or any other graphic tab), it simply says "No data available". Can you figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can find `settings` on the right side of chart buttons,
then you define `Keys`, `Groups`, `Values` as you like.

Comment: Is there any way to sort charts by values? My data is sorted by the chart x-axis is not.